# How to override ChartOptions of Chart.js component in other components in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js

I have a chart component and I am using it in different components. I would like to override ChartOptions in the component in which I am using chart component but It is not working. I am trying to hide the legend but It is taking the options which are initially assign to the component.

chart component typescript file

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

import { ChartDataSets, Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

import * as lMax from 'lodash/max';
import * as lCeil from 'lodash/ceil';

import {
  DEFAULT_CHART_MARGIN_TOP,
  lineChartOptions,
  lineChartPlugins
} from '/chart/chart.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() chartLabels: Label[];
  @Input() chartValues: ChartDataSets[] = [];

  public lineChartOptions = lineChartOptions;
  public lineChartPlugins = lineChartPlugins;

  public chart: Chart;

  @ViewChild('myChart', { static: true }) private chartRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.chartRef.nativeElement, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: this.chartLabels,
        datasets: this.chartValues
      },
      options: this.lineChartOptions,
      plugins: this.lineChartPlugins,
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.chartValues && changes.chartValues.currentValue[0]) {
      this.lineChartOptions = {
        ...this.lineChartOptions,
        scales: {
          ...this.lineChartOptions.scales,
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                fontColor: '#74736f',
                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                fontSize: 14,
                min: 0,
                padding: 12,
                stepSize: lCeil(lMax(changes.chartValues.currentValue[0].data) * DEFAULT_CHART_MARGIN_TOP / 4),
                suggestedMax: lCeil(lMax(changes.chartValues.currentValue[0].data) * DEFAULT_CHART_MARGIN_TOP),
                suggestedMin: 0
              }
            }
          ],
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Chart component html file

```js
<mat-card>
    <canvas
        #myChart
    ></canvas>
</mat-card>
```

chart component configuration file:

```js
import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';

export const DEFAULT_CHART_MARGIN_TOP = 1.1;

export const legendHeightPlugin = {
  beforeInit: function(chart) {
    chart.legend.afterFit = function() {
      this.height += 46;
    };
  }
};

export const lineChartPlugins = [
  legendHeightPlugin
];

export const lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: {
    align: 'start',
    display: true,
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 10,
      fontColor: '#1d1e20',
      fontFamily: 'Inter',
      fontSize: 12,
      usePointStyle: true
    },
    onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    },
    position: 'top'
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#74736f',
          fontFamily: 'Inter',
          fontSize: 14,
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 15,
          callback: (value: string) => {
            return value.substring(0, 1) + value.substring(1, 3).toLowerCase();
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 0,
      hoverRadius: 6
    }
  }
};
```

The chart configuration code in my other component typescript file

```js
public chartOptions : ChartOptions =  {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false,
      onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      },
      position: 'top'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            fontColor: '#74736f',
            fontFamily: 'Inter',
            fontSize: 14,
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 15,
            callback: (value: string) => {
              return value.substring(0, 1) + value.substring(1, 3).toLowerCase();
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
        hoverRadius: 6
      }
    }
  };
```

The chart code in my other component html file:

```html
<my-chart  [chartLabels]="lineChartLabels" [chartValues]="lineChartData" [options]="chartOptions"
    Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.display="false">
</my-chart>
```

If anyone knows how it will work then please let me know. Thanks